# How to check how many Users has registered in one week

Tags: php, mysql

How will the MySql statement look like? For example:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE` .......  ???

Is it going to be time less than - milliseconds? How can I put the current time ?

Comment: This is very, very basic - maybe looking at a mySQL tutorial is the way to go? Anyway, this needs more info about your table structure. What kind of a column is the time info in?

Comment: Also do you want the last 7 days or the current week, beginning from what day?

Comment: I know I am new to programming. Well my table has timestamp in it so . So i get the date when a particular user has registered. so like 

username password timeStamp

Comment: Users registered in last 7 days and i have to send a email after that but i can do that.

Comment: Did not getting what you want exactly ? Please put more details ?

Comment: From his comments below the question he seems to want the user info (to send them an email) - but this is all guesswork unless he actually posts requirements/ database, table structure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users 
WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(`date_registered`) <= 7
```

This query is or may be suboptimal for your specific case because there is very little known about the structure of your database. For more information please [refer to the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff).